# Equivalent for HEADER_RELEASE in spark datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5

I am trying to dispatch a sort event for s:DataGrid when user click on the column header.  Earlier I was using HEADER_RELEASE type with DataGridEvent to dispatch the sort events for mx:DataGrid like this.

```
var dge:DataGridEvent = new DataGridEvent(DataGridEvent.HEADER_RELEASE, false, false, Number(colIndex), widget.columns[Number(colIndex)].dataField, -1, null, null, NaN);  
widget.dispatchEvent(dge);
```

I could not find any such equivalent for s:datagrid. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks